# What is a type component in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, types

Angular documentation says that angular.Module is a type component. There are a few other type components in the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type). What exactly is a type component? Is it related to type system in programming languages? How does it differ from other components in angularjs like modules?